# Why do I get errors passing more conditions to this function

Tags: python, function

I thought of creating a function which will give a range of an input at the same time change the value if a certain condition is met.

```
def num(u) :
    for x in range(1,u): 
        if (x) %2==0:
            x ='love'
            print x
print num(10)
```

output :

```
1
love
3
love
5
love
7
love
9
```

'Wow this was great' (i thought). Then I decided to add more conditions to make my program look mature. Well it wasn't as I thought!!!

```
def num(u) :
    for x in range(1,u): 
        if (x) %2==0:
            x ='love'
            print x
        if (x) %3==0:
            x ='fux'
        if (x) %5==0:
            x ='buzz'
```

On printing I got :

```
output :
/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/bin/qpython.sh "/storage/sdcard0/qpython/scripts/.last_tmp.py" && exit
python/scripts/.last_tmp.py" && exit  <
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/storage/sdcard0/qpython/scripts/.last_tmp.py", line 8, in <module>
print num (10)
File "/storage/sdcard0/qpython/scripts/.last_tmp.py", line 5, in num
if (x) %3==0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
1|u0_a115@g150_g:/ $
```

How can I pass in more conditions at this point.

Comment: Why is it so hard to **first check if the question looks right** before posting?

Comment: are you sure you need `if` and not `elif`? Because the subsequent `if`s will execute regardless of the first triggering or not, but if it does trigger, `x` is no longer an integer but a string where `%` is used for string formatting and not modulo..

Comment: @willem..sorry about that I would correct it please

Comment: @ev..I thought they are similar

Comment: Giving us the desired output would speed things up dramatically btw + The first part of your question (the working bit) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the way you've set up your conditional statements. Think about what happens after one of the cases is true. After `x % 2 == 0` passes, you change the value of `x` to `"love"`. Any of the subsequent conditions will now be referencing the new value of `x`, and of course trying to use the modulus operation on a string doesn't make any sense, thus causing the error.

To fix this, use a different variable to store the resulting string, or simply print it directly, rather than overwriting the value of `x`.

An alternative would be to change the chain of `if` statements to an `if/elif/else` sequence, to guarantee that only one of the blocks of code will execute.

Comment: Thanks man... Am so grateful.. I did exactly what you said and it works

Comment: Happy to hear that it helped!

Answer (score 1):

If two of the `if`s are entered, `x` will be assigned a string, and no longer be an int, so you can't use the modulu operator on it (in fact, `%` is interpreted as the string format operator). You can clean up the code by just printing the strings you want without assigning them to `x`:

```
def num(u) :
    for x in range(1,u): 
        if (x) %2==0:
            print 'love'
        if (x) %3==0:
            print 'fux'
        if (x) %5==0:
            print 'buzz'
```

Comment: I have gotten it... It works correctly by directly printing out values and using the else statement

Comment: Thanks for putting me through... Am so much grateful

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but error is every simple. you can not perform mathematical operation on string, it has to be integer. Also, your code is not pythonic :)

```
def num(u):
for x in range(1, u):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        x = 'love'
        print x
    # Following code will throw error as now x is not INT     
    if x % 3 == 0:
        x = 'fux'
    if x % 5 == 0:
        x = 'buzz'
```